# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load NativeMorphoSmartSDK_6.13.2.0-4.1 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am getting null UnsatisfiedLinkError while building my app.

i am using openssl and some third party libraries to capture finger and verify them.

here is my cmake file

```
  # For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


             add_library(openssl SHARED IMPORTED)
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.so )
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.so )
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libidkit.so )
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libjnidispatch.so )
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libMSO100.so )
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libNativeMorphoSmartSDK_6.13.2.0-4.1.so )




# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

include_directories(openssl-armeabi-v7a/include/)
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.a

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

is this correct way of loading .so file in cmake or is there any method to load .so files . help with this issue

Comment: Unzip your resulting apk file and check that all the .so files are inside

Answer (score 0):

Each **.so** file that you list is a separate library. You must give each a separate name, e.g.

```
add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.so )
add_library(prebuilt_ssl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (prebuilt_ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.so )
add_library(idkit SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (idkit PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libidkit.so )
```

and so on. As you can see above, the logical name is not necessarily related to the file name.

If your **native-lib** depends on some of them, you can use these names:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
    native-lib foo prebuilt_ssl
    # Links the target library to the log library
    # included in the NDK.
    log )
```

---

Note that with NDK, you don't need `find_library` to add dependency on the android log library.

---

There is some self-contradiction in the CMake script that you posted. You should use OpenSSL libraries either as shared objects (as **libssl.so**), or static libraries (as **libssl.a**), but not both. It's OK to mix **libjnidispatch.so** together with **libssl.a**, but not **libcrypto.a** and **libssl.so**.

Comment: Nothing working sir..Actually my problem is i have two project one is built using Cmake(openssl project) and another built using Android.mk (Finger print Morpho project) ..in my new project i have to use both projects .so files ...I tried as in above Cmake as u seen.

Comment: If you want guidance, please be more specific. Hybrid CMake+Android.mk setup may be tricky. You probably don't make changes to openssl often. Then, I would advise to build this part separately, and reference it as prebuilt in your project.